# Estado en una iteración de componentes en React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui, gatsby

Tengo un componente padre que es mi template de carro.
Donde itero sobre un array para crear una lista de opciones de envío.

```
<div className="shipping-method-container">
  {shippingRates && shippingRates.map((rate, i) => {
  return  (<ShippingMethod 
           checkboxState={checkboxState}
           checkboxStateSetter={setCheckboxState}
           key={`${rate.node.stripe_shipping_id}-${i}`}
           dataFromParent={rate}/>)
})
}

</div>
```

En este componente padre tengo el estado y la función para cambiar el estado.

```
 const [checkboxState, setCheckboxState] = useState('');

  function handleCheckboxChange (value, dataFromChild) {
    setCheckboxState(value);
}
```

Y luego en el componente hijo tengo la UI que necesito.
El componente Checkbox es de Semantic UI React.

```
export const ShippingMethod = ({
  customCSS,
  dataFromParent, 
  checkboxState,
  checkboxStateSetter
}) => {


      
      const [shippingRateID, setShippingRateID] = useState("")

      useEffect(() => {
        setShippingRateID(dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_id)
      }, [])
     
      const currencySymbol = getCurrencySymbol(dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.currency)

      const min = dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate === null ? "" : dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate.minimum.value

      const max = dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate === null ? "" : dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate.maximum.value



      function handleClick(value, data) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("shipping_rate", dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_id)
      }

  return (
    <div className={["component_ShippingMethod", customCSS ].join(" ")}>
        <div className="shipping-method-first-line">
            <p >
            <Checkbox 
                radio
                type="checkbox"
                id={"shipping_rate"}
                name="shipping_rate"
                value={shippingRateID}
                onChange={(e, data) => checkboxStateSetter(e.target.value, data)}
                checked={checkboxState === shippingRateID}
                onClick={(e, data)=> handleClick(e.target.value, data)}
            />
            &nbsp;  {dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.display_name} {shippingRateID}
            </p>
          <p>{currencySymbol}{dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.amount/100}</p>
        </div>
      <p className="shipping-method-second-line"> {min} - {max} business days</p>
    </div>
    )
}
```

La UI se renderiza bien. Sin problemas.
Pero curiosamente, cuando selecciono uno de los Shipping rates, es decir, hago click en uno de los componentes hijo. Solo me envia al session Storage (y muestra cómo checkeado el checkbox) del primero.
React pareciara no interpretar diferentes componentes. Aunque sí muestra en la UI diferentes ID's y diferente información por cada uno.
Algunas Ideas ??

Comment: Por favor verifica  con `console.log` y ayudanos confirmando, si los valores de `sesionstorage. shipping_rate` cambian cada que el usuario selecciona un checkbox distinto de la lista, ya que eso parece funcionar bien. El problema parece estar en la presentación de los checkbox (cual debe quedar seleccionado).

Comment: Hola, no. El session storage tampoco se actualiza. Solo guarda el primero en la lista.

Comment: Hay dos problemas, insertar un array de `checked id's` en `sessionStorage`, y manejar el estado `checkboxState` de forma dinámica. Sugiero verificar el estado `dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_id` para cada componente `ShippingMethod ` en consola; se espera ver un `stripe_shipping_id` diferente en cada uno de ellos. Si puedes confirmar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finalmente encontré respuesta en este articulo de Free Code Camp
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-work-with-multiple-checkboxes-in-react/

Cambie muchas cosas.

El nuevo componente hijo quedo asi

```
{shippingRates && shippingRates.map((rate, index) => {
                          //  console.log(`raterate : ${JSON.stringify(rate, null, 2)}`)
                            return  (<ShippingMethod 
                              key={`${index}`}
                              checked={checkedState[index]}
                              onClick={() => handleOnChange(index, rate)}
                              index={index}
                              dataFromParent={rate}/>)
                            })
                          }
```

Donde se ve que cambie el manejo del estado de los checkbox. y les paso como una prop si es true o false.
En el componente padre inicio el estado de los checkbox como un array, donde cada uno tiene el valor false y luego el handler, usando el indice, cambia a true el checkbox clickeado. (onClick handler)

Estado en el componente padre + el onClick handler llamado "handleOnChange"

```
 const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(new Array(shippingRates.length).fill(false));

  const handleOnChange = (position, rate) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) => {
      console.log(`item on iteration: ${item}`);
      return index === position ? true : false;
    }
    );
    sessionStorage.setItem("shipping_rate", rate.node.stripe_shipping_id)
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
    setShippingCost(parseFloat(rate.node.stripe_shipping_rate.amount/100).toFixed(2))

  };
```

Por ultimo, una cosa muy importante que cambie en el componente hijo es fue vincular el ID del checkbox con el  correspondiente. Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
export const ShippingMethod = ({
  customCSS,
  dataFromParent, 
  onClick,
  checked,
  index
}) => {

    const getCurrencySymbol = currency => {
        if (!currency) return "£"
    
        const symbols = [
          { currency: "gbp", symbol: "£" },
          { currency: "eur", symbol: "€" },
          { currency: "usd", symbol: "$" },
          { currency: "aud", symbol: "$" },
        ]
        const result = symbols.find(
          x => x.currency.toLowerCase() === currency.toLowerCase()
        )
    
        const { symbol } = result
    
        return symbol
      }

      
      const [shippingRateID, setShippingRateID] = useState("")

      useEffect(() => {
        setShippingRateID(dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_id)
      }, [])
     
      const currencySymbol = getCurrencySymbol(dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.currency)

      const min = dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate === null ? "" : dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate.minimum.value

      const max = dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate === null ? "" : dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.delivery_estimate.maximum.value

    
     
    
  return (
    <div className={["component_ShippingMethod", customCSS ].join(" ")}>
        <div className="shipping-method-first-line">
            <p >
            <Checkbox 
                radio
                type="checkbox"
                id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                name="shipping_rate"
                value={shippingRateID}
                onClick={() => onClick()}
                checked={checked}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>
            &nbsp;  {dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.display_name}
            </label>
            </p>
          <p>{currencySymbol}{dataFromParent.node.stripe_shipping_rate.amount/100}</p>
        </div>
      <p className="shipping-method-second-line"> {min} - {max} business days</p>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Por si queda cualquier duda recomiendo leer el artículo completo.
Gracias a quienes colaboraron en la respuesta.